# Preventing overwrites from concurrent forms in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns

We're setting up a system which allows a department to make edits to a record here. Their division of labor isn't clear, and they've had problems in the past where more than one individual loads data into a web form, makes edits, and then sends those edits to the record. Inevitably, the slower editor over-writes the faster editor's freshly edited data with the old data that had been loaded when the page loaded.

Currently, we have a white-board solution that would use changes to the last modified time of the data to reject the second request to write data and deliver an error message when that data POSTED.

The members of the department, however, would prefer a file-lock styled system--one where they were notified that another user was in the dataset *prior* to being allowed to access the data. Timeouts will inevitably be too short or too long depending on the day, and these particular users cannot be relied upon to "log out" somehow.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has implemented a solution to this, and, if so, **how**?

We're running PHP 5.6 on Apache 2.2 and building in Zend Framework 2.4. Not that any of that has any bearing on the question, but someone will inevitably ask.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this site mostly is a code problem solving community.

Comment: Save hashes of the existing date before edit. When updating check that the hashes haven't changed. Report where different when updating etc. No record 'locking' needed therefore  no need to unlock records.

Comment: When starting an editor, you could store some information in a table, so if someone else wants to edit this information, you can show a message if there is still a record for another editor. Of course you have to expire this information too, because one might close the editor, or leave it open all night, or his browser might crash, so maybe the editor needs to send keepalives to the server, or the server must expire an edit session (of which the editor should also be notified). Another solution is to show the diferences when there is a conflict, like MediaWiki does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 columns to your table `locked_by_user_id` and `locked_time`.

Before you allow a user to enter the "edit" view, check if those values are set and if `locked_time` is within the past 10 minutes. The reason you should record the locked time instead of a binary flag is because, as you say, some people forget to log out or might not log out cleanly (for example, they could just close their browser).

When someone is able to acquire a lock, set up a `setInterval` that runs every 5 minutes that reacquires the lock via an ajax call. Someone still might forget to leave the "edit" screen but in that case you can allow someone else to override a lock and if that happens you can have the ajax call exit the "edit" screen when it fails to reacquire the lock.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a flag on the table row for edit_in_progress? If a user clicks to edit and that flag is already set, fail out with a message saying someone else is editing it (perhaps consider also setting a field for WHO is editing it, so they can go back in before they've saved and continue their edits). Once saved, unset both fields, and allow the next user to lock the row.

Comment: I have a user set who are likely to wander off for a smoke, or lunch, or even a vacation. Heck, they might leave it open and retire. :) In the end, this ends up back at "timing out" because some of these things are edited in a couple minutes, other take an hour or more. And because of that, timing out is a tough thing to get right (if it's even possible.)

Although I might be able to work in the "who." That's a nice touch.

Comment: Consider setting an expiry flag as well. If after N minutes the edit has not been completed, have a cron job unflag it and notify the user their edits have been lost due to inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using a database, but not knowing  the database schema you're using, this is going to be a generic answer.

You need to give each record an identifier which is set as non-unique. By this, I mean each record could be identified as `record_1`, `record_2` ... `record_n` but this identifier can appear multiple times in the table.

When a record is edited, don't update the record directly but create a new record which is

- timestamped
- has the original `record_n` identifier

Also, add a field to the record to give its current state (e.g. `stable`, `editing`?) and a field which gives the edit start date/time if it is being edited

With this, when someone wants to edit a record (e.g., `record_2`), you retrieve the most recent data for this record and check its state (if marked as `editing` then report this and prevent concurrent editing).

When they submit changes, a new timestamped record is created in the database, you mark the old and new records as stable.

Using this, you also create a paper-trail for auditing changes

With regards to people who wander off/retire/die and leave records in an editied state, create a scheduled job which resets states to "stable" after a preset number of minutes (60?)